# Unable to use same form for inserting and updating using php and ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have many forms in a page. I want to use same form for saving and editing form . I want to use ajax and php to save and edit records and wants to disable save button after clicking save button and enable edit button and vice versa. Please help me.

I have form similar like this.

```
<form id="a" onsubmit="return func();">
       <input type="text" name="fname">
       <input type="text" name="lname">
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit" id="saveButton" value="save" style="height:40px;width:70px">
                           <input type="submit" id="editButton" value="edit" style="height:40px;width:70px">
      </form>
```

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
 function func(){   
    $.ajax({
        url     : "registration_detail.php", // in this you got serialize form data via post request
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $('#a').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
     return false;
}
function func(){   
    $.ajax({
        url     : "update_application.php", // in this you got serialize form data via post request
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $('#a').serialize(),
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
     return false;
}

    </script>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#saveButton").click(function(){
 $("#saveButton").attr("disabled", true);
   $("#editButton").attr("enabled", true);
  });
  $("#editButton").click(function(){
  $("#editButton").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#saveButton").attr("enabled", true);
  });
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this exemple :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>



<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<p>Exemple</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your script, you have  created two functions with same name.

```
<form id="a">
       <input type="text" name="fname">
       <input type="text" name="lname">
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="button" id="saveButton" onclick="funcAdd();"value="save" style="height:40px;width:70px">
       <input type="button" id="editButton" onclick="funcUpdate()" value="edit" style="height:40px;width:70px">
      </form>



<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#saveButton").click(function(){
 $("#saveButton").attr("disabled", true);
   $("#editButton").attr("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#editButton").click(function(){
  $("#editButton").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#saveButton").attr("disabled", false);
  });
});
    </script>

<script>
 function funcAdd(){   
    console.log("in Add");
        $.ajax({
        url     : "registration_detail.php", // in this you got serialize form data via post request
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $('#a').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
     return false;
}
function funcUpdate(){   
    console.log("in update");   
    $.ajax({
        url     : "update_application.php", // in this you got serialize form data via post request
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $('#a').serialize(),
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
     return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: please share me your php script which you are using for update form.

Comment: @prabinashrestha check now I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm unable to use same form for  create and update using php and ajax.  My php code https://dpaste.de/oiW0. Please help me.@Galaxy Patel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. And change attributes value in ajax response if get success

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on("submit", function(){
        var submitted_form_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#"+submitted_form_id+"_save").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#"+submitted_form_id+"_save").attr("type", "button");
        $("#"+submitted_form_id+"_edit").attr("type", "submit");
    })
})
```